# File handling using Python - Print daily value sums

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I need to write a function print_daily_totals(filename) that takes the name of such a file as a parameter and reads the data from the file, printing the total of the readings for each day in the format given below.

Days should be printed out in the same order as in the input file.

For each line in the input file I should print an output line in the format date = total, with the total given to 2 decimal places. For example, with the simple 2-line input file above, the output would be:

> ```
> 2010-01-01 = 30.00
> 2010-01-02 = 115.30
> ```

The file contains:

> ```
> 2006-04-10,836.2,563.263
> 2006-04-11,462.06,1694.3,666.0
> 2006-04-12,1318.19,1485.62
> ```

The call statement will be

> ```
>  print_daily_totals('data.txt')
> ```
>
> The expected output must be:
>
> ```
>  2006-04-10 = 1399.46
>  2006-04-11 = 2822.36
>  2006-04-12 = 2803.81
> ```

I am still beginning file handling in Python. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and which part you are having difficulty with.

Comment: I know how to do basic arithmetic operations..and how to convert numbers to two decimal places..but I am stuck when combining this with file handling operations.

Comment: Is there only one line per day or could there be days spread over several lines?

Comment: Only one line per day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
def print_daily_totals(ff):
    with open(ff) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line_arr = line.split(',')
            result = sum([float(amnt.strip()) for amnt in line_arr[1:]])
            print(line_arr[0]+" = "+ str(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

```
def print_daily_totals(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:            #Open file for read
        for line in infile:                   #Iterate each line
            val = line.strip().split(",")     #split line by comma
            print("{} = {}".format(val[0], sum(map(float, val[1:]))))

print_daily_totals('data.txt')
```

**Output:**

```
2006-04-10 = 1399.463
2006-04-11 = 2822.36
2006-04-12 = 2803.81
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet can do the job:

```
def print_daily_totals(file_path):
    f = open(file_path)
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(',')
        date = values.pop(0)
        total = sum(float(val) for val in values)
        print(date, '=', "{:.2f}".format(total))
```

Comment: The penultimate line has an extra ")", please get rid of it :)

Comment: This is much simpler than mine..Thanks Ben.